# Float percentage producing wrong answer

Tags: java, android

```
System.out.println("Percentage (90): " + (_leftBranch.getHeight() / 100) * 90 + " Height: " + _leftBranch.getHeight());
```

Gives the output:

```
Percentage (90): 270 Height: 359
```

When infact it should be 323.1.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: Cast to double before division, or divide by 100.0

Comment: When you divide two integers the remain integers: 359 / 100 = 3, 3 * 90 = 270, Peter Lawrey's answer addresses how to use decimals.

Comment: Thanks guys learned an important lesson here. I though those numbers would automatically turn into floats, obviously the compiler isn't that smart :-P

Comment: Nope. It is intentional.

Comment: Exactly, you don't want to inadvertently get a float while dividing. If you tell the compiler you want an int, that's what you'll get.You need to be careful with your numbers. Especially when integer division renders a zero, such as 9/10, and you use it later, for division or whatever. For your case of percentage, a good rule of thumb for is: multiply first, divide later. You'll get more accuracy that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the calculations are done in integer type.

Put 100.0 and 90.0 instead of 100 and 90

The first part of calculation results in 3.59. But it only considers integer part which is 3 thus the result 270

Answer (score 2):

You calculate 90% by

```
x * 90 / 100
```

or

```
x * 9 / 10
```

or if overflow is a concern

```
x - x / 10
```

If you expect a decimal result you can do

```
x * 0.9
```

or

```
x * 0.90
```

Answer (score 1):

Dividing `/` two `integers` also will return integer (remainder of division will be ignored).

Try `(_leftBranch.getHeight() / 100d) * 90` for better results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following...

```
System.out.println("Percentage (90): " + (_leftBranch.getHeight() / 100.0) * 90.0 + " Height: " + _leftBranch.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this -

```
System.out.println("Percentage (90): " + (_leftBranch.getHeight() / 100D) * 90 + " Height: " + _leftBranch.getHeight());
```